# Gitlab burnup chart that projects forward

Tags: gitlab, forecast, burndowncharts

We're using GitLab (which I'm new to) and I've got issues set in a Milestone and can see the Burndown and Burnup charts it creates.
But it is only plotting actual data and I'm looking for a forecast based on actual velocity.

Any tips to get this?